# Area projection from cube to sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, cartography

I have a regular cube of edge length = 2, and a sphere of radius = 1. Each face of the cube has been divided into N*N equal-area squares. How can I compute the projected area of every square on the sphere, so that the area of all the projections sum up to 4*pi.

I came to the following solution but the result does not sum to 4*pi:

1. Denote the area of each square on the cube as: A
2. Denote the length of the line segment connecting the center of the cube with the center of a square on the cube face as: R
3. Then I compute the cosine of the angle between the above line segment with a face normal (ex. if the square lies in +X face, then the angle is between the line segment and the normal of face +X).

so that the projection of the area from the square to the sphere can be computed as:

A * cosine(angle) / R^2

However, the above solution does not sum to 4*pi

Comment: This -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateralized_spherical_cube -- map projection might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is a (very) good approximation when `N` is (very) large.

If you want the exact formula, you will need to compute an integral (over the little square of area `A` of the function `cos/R^2`).